# Add calculated count value to a formula which act as cell reference no

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some range of data in F5:F25 , ansd these data can be append on daily basic  , which can make them f5:30 on next day.
Instaed of daily slected the range , i am counting the rows , says 25 as output.

Now i need to put this 25 in F5:F(25) here.

Doing it by f5:f&( Cell refence where 25 is calucated ) but getting name error

Comment: Is "Cell refence where 25 is calucated "  means that the formula u r entering is located at row 25 cells ?

Comment: i am counting row in a cell , which give output say 25.  and i what you use this output in range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u r looking for

```
=INDIRECT("F5:F"&ROW())
```

please confirm if that is the case..

idea : use `INDIRECT()` + `row()` that changes the formula reference at every row.

Comment: Thankyou , got the solution , it will perfectly fine and this is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You may use `INDEX()` or `INDIRECT()`. Try-

```
=F5:INDEX(F5:F50000,COUNTA(F5:F50000))
```